# How to do rank-1 factorization in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, factorization

I have a matrix M of dimensions 6x6 and it has rank 1. How can I factorize it into two matrices of dimensions 6x1 (say A) and 1x6 (say B) so that M=A*B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take the largest eigen vector and multiply it by the largest eigenvalue :

```
 A=[1 2 3 4]'*[1 2 3 4]
 A =

     1     2     3     4
     2     4     6     8
     3     6     9    12
     4     8    12    16

 [v,e] = eigs(A,1);
 sqrt(e)*v
 ans =

   -1.0000
   -2.0000
   -3.0000
   -4.0000
```

of course, the result is good only up to a sign change.

**EDIT**:
if you assume that the two vectors can be different:

```
A=[1 2 3 4]'*[5 6 7 8]
[uu,ss,vv]=svd(A);
u=uu(:,1)*ss(1,1)
v=vv(:,1)
assert(norm(u*v'-A)<1E-10)
```

Now the solution is even less unique. You are determining 2*n values based on only n. This is one solution among many.

For example, look at this other even simpler solution (which will assume your matrix is perfectly rank 1) :

```
aa=A(:,:)./repmat(A(1,:),[size(A,1),1]);
bb=A(:,:)./repmat(A(:,1),[1,size(A,2)]);
u=aa(:,1);
v=bb(1,:)'*A(1);
assert(norm(u*v'-A)<1E-10)
```

it produces a totally different result, but that still factorizes the matrix. If you want non-negative factorizations only to slightly reduce the space of possible results, I'd suggest you ask a new question!

Comment: You are assuming that for M=A*B, A=B', which is not what I want.

Comment: ouch, indeed, let me think a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

If it has rank 1, then all columns/rows are multiples of the first column/row (or indeed of any non-zero column/row).  i.e.:

```
m = M(:,1);
M = [ a*m, b*m, c*m, d*m, e*m, f*m ];
```

Hopefully you can take it from there.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand it. What are a-f?

Comment: @WaqarHameed: Scalar values.  I'm leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out their values.

Comment: I am sorry. The goal of this question was to determine how precisely are the two matrices obtained. Your answer does not seem to indicate it.

Comment: @WaqarHameed: It really should follow straight from the giant clue above.  Here's a further hint: `a` is always `1`.  What would `b` have to be to correctly generate the 2nd column of `M`?

Comment: @WaqarHameed: A*B can be viewed as multiplying the vector A each time by a different number given by the elements of B. So the 1st column of M would be A multiplied by the 1st element in B, the 2nd column of M would be A multiplied by the 2nd element of B, and so on. So you can arbitrarily set A to be equal the first column of M, which makes the 1st element of B equal 1. Now continue from there.